# Airplay doesn't work on Raspberry pi running OSMC - IOS 9

Tags: osmc, pi-b+

I am trying to play audio through my Raspberry Pi  from my iPhone(running IOS 9).  I can see the name of the pi under AirPlay, but it deselects whenever I click on it.  I had read that OSMC didn't work with IOS 9, but those articles were old.  Can anyone clarify this for me?  Thanks in advance!